# How to run scheduled task in AWS?

Tags: java, aws-lambda, scheduled-tasks

I have a school application. Where the teacher can send mail to each parent. Parent has to check email and confirm (reply) back in 2 days .

If the parent does not respond back we automatically need to send out second followup email.

Parent response will be parsed in Lambda and same will be updated in database. so that we should not send followup email .

I am using Amazon SES for sending the email.
**How can implement wait for 2 days logic** ? should I use lambda function or JScheduler ?

Comment: I'd suggest you to use Spring Scheduling. Please refer to the [link](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-scheduled-tasks).

Comment: okay will check

Comment: It is very easy to use. Try implement on that and whether still in doubt, post your code here and we can provide more help.

Comment: Sure - I thought if Amazon had something for it. wanted to do the serverless implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can implement wait for 2 days logic ?

You may use [AWS Step functions](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/) which is statefull state-machine workflow. The service implements a *wait task* you may use to way for 2 days